# How do I 'zero' an array in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I an array of 6 booleans :

```pascal
stages: Array [0..5] of Boolean;
```

I'd like to reset it before using it, but this isn't a valid operation according to the Delphi Rio compiler :

```pascal
stages := [False, False, False, False, False, False];
```

So how can I express this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you explicitly declare a type for your array you can use the [finally documented](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Default) `Default` intrinsic.

```
type
  TMyBoolArray = array[0..5] of Boolean;
var
  stages: TMyBoolArray;
begin
  stages := Default(TMyBoolArray);
```

Comment: It's not documented particularly *well* though...

Comment: Voted  as usefull because I never knew this. :)

Comment: Oof that documentation is terrible!

Comment: Oh, very nice ! Didn't know about the Default() function. Unfortunately that means needing to declare a type, which is always annoying but oh well.

Comment: @muchos Indeed, that is why I requested this some while ago: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31800

Comment: Declaring a type is not annoying. It gives the opportunity to comment the code without using comments.

Comment: @UweRaabe Yes, it is annoying if you have no plans of using the type in more then once place. In which case, you're just cluttering the code and making it harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

```
FillChar(Stages,Sizeof(Stages),False);
```

Answer (score 0):

The more <s>simple and safe</s> **easy to understand** (*later edit due to the good arguments of Andreas in the comments*) answer to your problem is this:

In declaration area:

```
  const TopStage = 5;
  var
    stages: Array [0..TopStage] of Boolean;
```

Then, you could set every elment in a loop like this:

```
for var I := 0 to TopStage do 
  stages[I] := False;
```

If you had a dynamic array (`stages: Array of Boolean`) or (`stages: TArray<Boolean>`) then you could do what you tried:

```
stages := [False, False, False, False, False, False];
```

Comment: You should elaborate on what you mean by "simple and safe". Arguably it is "simpler" because it is more obvious to beginners and "safer" because the `FillChar` approach *must not be used on managed types* (like `array of string`) because that would mess up the compiler's (and RTL's) reference counting machinery. On the other hand, your suggested approach is certainly NOT simple in the 'brief' or 'concise' sense. Also, it is not "safe" since you hardcoded the array bounds `0` and `5`. That's almost like asking for trouble in the future. At least `5` should be `High(stages)`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I chose the word "simple", as in "easy to understand" by all no matter the level of understanding and the word "safe", because the beginners should not abuse this function, simply because of situation you described. Also, I hardcoded  the bounds because of simplicity (again, as in easy to understand), faster then appealing to the Low and High functions, and because the coder stated that he only needed a array of 6 elements (not more or less). What I would do in a real situation, is declare a constant NumberOfStages that  would be easy to change in the future if needed.